# Multiple Google Analytic property ids in One Google Tag Manager tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can we add multiple Google Analytic property ids in a one Google Tag Manager tag?

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to do this with a look-up table.

In my setup, I just insert {{UA Lookup Table}} into the UA ID. It will then check against the hostname and assign the correct one for that domain.

If you mean report to several different UA codes - then no. You have to create a new tag for each pageview/event report. Use 'copy tag'.

[image: Google Tag Manager Lookup Table]

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternate method, you could also fire a tag multiple times without having to create tag copies by doing some fancy Custom HTML work, as outlined here: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/firing-a-single-tag-multiple-times-in-gtm/#gref